# Android Instrumentation Unit testing an adapter that requires a reference to an activity

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, instrumentation

I have inherited some messy code that I am trying to clean up. The first thing I'm starting with is writing some unit tests on the module's that I am planning on keeping for a while. Unfortunately, one of these is a custom adapter which requires a pointer to an activity (because it makes a call to getWindowManager() ). As soon as I started trying to write this test code, I immediately discovered a gap in my testing knowledge. How do I pass a pointer to an activity to the object I am testing?

I could launch a dedicated test activity? Should I be looking at the ActivityUnitTestCase instead of AndroidTestCase? All of these seem like messy solutions to what must be a relatively common problem? Does anyone know how to pass a pointer to an activity in android instrumentation testing without having that activity actually being the object under test?

Thanks in advance!!

Avtar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the correct way to do this is with AndroidUnitTestCase and use a dummy activity which your actual object being tested can point to. If anyone has any better suggestions let me know!

Comment: Did you ever find a better option to this?